# MVC Pattern: What other Pattern to use with it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have developed a MVC web application with ASP.NET MVC and im just wondering which Pattern you prefer to use with a MVC project?

Comment: Are you talking about data patterns?

Comment: Hey, MVC is a pattern! Use that! :)

Comment: Hmm... I think im asking this the wrong, unfortunaly i don't know how i should ask the quesstion otherwise, so i think im read up on Andrews articles, they look nice. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly vague question!  I have written quite a few articles over on DotNetSlackers that specifcally walk you through from a simple ASP.NET MVC application where the web page connects directly to the data source (think standard MS tutorial) all the way through to a full distributed nTier style application where the presentation connects via WCF to business layer (allowing business components to exist on seperate servers) which then connects to a data source through a pluggable data access layer (this last couple of articles I am still writing).

Get started reading these here: http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/StackOverflowInspiredKnowledgeExchange/ in the Three Tiers to MVC section.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange--Three-Tiers-to-MVC-Hooray-A-simple-MVC-application.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Three-Tiers-to-MVC-Hooray-Logical-Separation.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Building-a-StackOverflow-inspired-Knowledge-Exchange-Three-Tiers-to-MVC-Hooray-Physical-Separation.aspx

Reversing dependencies article will be published in the next couple of days and the remaining articles will be out next week (roughly).

Answer (score 2):

The one that suites the problem. Now, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

None, It's not a good idea to use a pattern for the sake of using a pattern.  Design patterns solve a specific problem, and if you don't have that problem, don't use the pattern.

Comment: He may be referring to data patterns...which would still be applicable. Active Record, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't 100% sure either, but the question was tagged design-patterns, so I went with that.